# How to unlink a node from a singly linked list and store the unlinked nodes pointer?

Tags: c, linked-list

I have been looking around for some sample code on how to unlink (not delete) a node from a singly linked list. My aim is to unlink the node and store its pointer so that I can later possible link it back somewhere in the linked list.

Does anyone know how I might be able to do this?

This is my structure:

```
 struct Courses{
        char *courseName;
        int creditValue;
        Courses *next;
    };Courses;

struct Student{
        char *name;
        int age;
        Courses *list;  //First course (node) for Courses linked list.
    }Student;
```

Example of what I am trying to do:

I have the following linked list:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5
```

Now I want to unlink 3 and store its location somewhere else.

```
1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 5

3  (Stored somwhere)
```

Then in the end I want to link 3 back somewhere in the list. For now lets say I want it after 4.

```
1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 3 -> 5
```

Hope this helps further explain.

Comment: problem not clear. can you given few examples?

Comment: @aksam Edited to further explain.

Answer (score 0):

To "unlink" a node is simply to change the `next` domain of the node that was pointing to it.

You can of course keep the pointer of the unlinked node, and use this node later. Unlinking is not the same as releasing the memory allocated to the node.

For example, the following function unlinks the first node and returns it:

```
Courses * GetFirstCourse(Student * s)
{
    Courses * result = s -> list;
    if (result)
    {
        s -> list = result -> next;
    }
    return result;
}
```

If you want to unlink a node in the middle, then you should keep track of the node preceding it, so that you can glue them back to a linked list.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the unlinking code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Courses {
    char *courseName;
    int creditValue;
    struct Courses *next;
} Courses;

typedef struct Student {
    char *name;
    int age;
    Courses *list;              // First course (node) for Courses linked list.
} Student;

Courses *
delink(Student *student,Courses *remove)
{
    Courses *prev;
    Courses *cur;

    prev = NULL;

    for (cur = student->list;  cur != NULL;  prev = cur, cur = cur->next) {
        if (cur == remove) {
            if (prev != NULL)
                prev->next = cur->next;
            else
                student->list = cur->next;
            cur->next = NULL;
            break;
        }
    }

    return remove;
}
```

Note that you'd probably have to be more explicit about the conditions necessary for the relink. That is, how do you want to "find" the reinsertion point, etc? Do you want to scan by `creditValue` or have you already got a `Courses *insert_after`?

Comment: Yes. [Obviously], it assumes you have a pointer to the node you wish to remove [caller already found this, based on some criteria]. The code will remove the node (herein `remove`) from _any_ place in the list: front, back, middle. It does _not_ do a "search for node by data values", it assumes caller has done that. Such an all-in-one function would be (e.g.): `Courses *find_and_delink(Student *student,char *course_name,int credit_value)`. That's what I meant at the bottom of my answer. You need to think about what/how many list functions you need, aside from how they're implemented